# while loop - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I tried to write a `while`  loop that let a user insert a number. And Python will summarize n+0.5 util it will get to the user's number.

I wrote:

```
num_u=float(input('insert a number'))
num_a=0

while num_a<num_u: 
    num_a=(num_a+0.5)
    print(num_a)

print(num_a)
```

I inserted the number 2.6 and received:

```
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.0
2.5
3.0
```

what is wrong? Why don't I get

```
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
```

Comment: Because `int(2.6) == 2`, not `3`. `int()` **floors**, it does not round.

Comment: and besides, continually adding 0.5 in a loop leads to floating point accumulation error. You'd be better off with integers & divide by 2 if you're going to fix that 0.5 step.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Are you sure about that? 0.5 can still be represented exactly in floats.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: 0.5 happens to be cleanly representable in floating point. As long as the other number is close enough in terms of the exponent, you'd not see any errors accumulate.

Comment: right! because it's a power of 2. But I wouldn't rely on that for any values.

Comment: Also it makes sense you get twice the same number at the end, as at the end of the while loop you get your final number and reprint it when you escape the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are flooring the input:

```
while num_a<int(num_u):
```

`int(2.6)` is `2`, not `3`, so the last number that's lower is `1.5`; `2.0 < 2` is false and the loop ends.

I'm not sure why you are converting to an integer at all; removing the `int()` call produces your desired output:

```
while num_a < num_u:
```

albeit with `2.5` printed twice (once by `print()` in the `while` loop, then again by the final `print()` outside the loop).

If you expected to *round* the number, then your expected output is incorrect. Looping until `3` would not only print `2.5`, but `3.0` too. You round floating point numbers with the [`round()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). If you wanted to get the ceiling (always round *up*) you'd need to use [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil).

If you wanted to list all numbers in `0.5` steps that are *lower or equal* to your end number, you need to alter your code to only print those numbers that are still lower:

```
num_a = 0.5
while num_a < num_u:
    print(num_a)
    num_a += 0.5
```

Note that we print `num_a` **before** adding 0.5 to it (and we started at `0.5`).

If swapping the `print()` statement and incrementing are not an option for you, you need to alter your test to add `0.5` first:

```
num_a = 0
while num_a + 0.5 < num_u:
    num_a += 0.5
    print(num_a)
```

Comment: because it doesn't work with out int. if I write 2.8 the last result is 3 not 2.5 even if I wrote "while num_a<num_u"

Comment: @m.k.l: no, because `2.5 < 2.8` is true, so you add `0.5` again. You want to start `num_a = 0.5` then, and move the print to *before* you add another `0.5`. Or use `while num_a + 0.5 < num_u:`.

Comment: because in the while I wrote that num_a=num_a+0.5

Comment: @m.k.l: also **in future** include in your question that you tried without `int()` and why that didn't work.

Comment: I use "int" because in the input number you can insert a float number. without "float' you can't insert 2.8. the best answer was to write  num_a<=int(num_u) but now if I write 2 I recive ; 0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5

Comment: No, because `int(num_u)` is 2, and thus you'll never get the correct results. The loop outcome would be the same for any user input value from `2.0` through to `2.99999999999999999999999999`.

Comment: I meant float. yet this code doesn't work:num_u=float(input('insert a number'))
num_a=-0.5

while num_a<num_u: 
    num_a=(num_a+0.5)
    print(num_a)
    
print('the final number is', num_a)

Comment: @m.k.l: why did you start with `-0.5` there? *How* doesn't it work? `num_u` is already a `float` value, so converting it to `float` *again* won't work.

Comment: it's not. try it by yourself. The user can't insert a flaot number without the order "float". Any way, it still not work: I want the while will stop when num_a<num_u. if the user insert the num. 1.8 I want the last result to be 1.5 not 2...

Comment: you did'nt use "input".

Comment: @m.k.l: how is `input()` material to your question? `float(input(...))` produces a float value. I skipped that step as it is **not material to the loop** how the float object was obtained.

Comment: @m.k.l: adding input is trivial however, and doesn't change the outcome: https://ideone.com/01S4LW

Comment: you right it work but why I should write " num_a += 0.5" and not "num_a=num_a+0.5"

Comment: @m.k.l: just shorter syntax.

Comment: oh I didn't learn it yet. what it means? (num_a +) = (num_a + 0.5) + 0.5?

Comment: @m.k.l: for numbers, it means exactly the same things as `num_a = num_a + 0.5`.

Comment: oh god! so my mistake was that I start the while with num_a and not  num_a + 0.5 < num_u (the next number after num_a should be lesser than num_a and not the current num_a). Thank you! truly thank! I even learned something new. best

Comment: @MartijnPieters given the number of comments, you well deserve it (and an upvote). Too bad you're not mentionning that it works by sheer luck because `0.5` value doesn't trigger any floating point accumulation errors. `0.4` would have.

Answer (score 1):

2.5 < 2.6, hence num_a = 2.5 is allowed to run through the while loop. Because of this, when 2.5 is passed into:

```
num_a=(num_a+0.5)
print(num_a)
```

You get 3 which it then prints, where as you wish to have the reverse, i.e., printing 2.5 and then adding 0.5.

To solve the problem, use the following:

```
num_a=0.5

while num_a<num_u: 
    print(num_a)
    num_a=(num_a+0.5)
```

This way, when num_a = 2.5 it will print the statement before it adds 0.5. The loop will then terminate without printing 3.0.

As a final precaution, make sure you don't get confused by your final print statement which is outside of the while loop. This will still give out 3, making it seem like the loop is erroneous.

```
print(num_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are casting the float to an integer.

```
while num_a<int(num_u):
```

Converting a float to an integer using the int() cuts the numbers behind the point.

So for example:

- int(2.6) is 2
- int(9.8) is 9

You have to make sure, it will keep the floating point number.

- float(2.6) is 2.6
- float(9.8) is 9.8

You are able to use the function without casting the given number, because you casted it once the user entered it.

```
num_u=float(input('insert a number'))
```

**The correct code is**

```python
num_u=float(input('insert a number'))
num_a=0

while num_a < num_u: # Replaced int(num_u) with num_u to keep float
    num_a = (num_a+0.5)
    print(num_a)

print(num_a)
```

Comment: `num_u` is **already a float**. There is no point in converting it to float again for the `while` test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to round to 0.5 to my knowledge if that is indeed the plan to get it rounded on halfs and then compared this seems to work:

```
num_u=float(input('insert a number'))

def roundhalfs(num):
    digit = num- int(num)
    digit = round(digit*2)/2
    return int(num) + digit

num_a=0
while num_a<roundhalfs(num_u):
    num_a=(num_a+0.5)
    print(num_a)

print(num_a)
```

*EDIT:* Some output:

```
insert a number2.8
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0

insert a number2.6
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
```

Comment: check your code.. it's printing 2.5 twice for 2.6 and 3.0 twice for 2.8

Comment: that is because he prints it again after the iteration is finished in order to remove that the last print just needs to be removed. I was under the impression as he done that that it was desired to print the final answer again

Comment: The OP wasn't all that clear about their edge-cases. They want to print `2.5` for `2.8` as well. There is no rounding needed here, only better boundary testing.

Comment: That is true however he increments with 0.5 so it suggests he want to stop at the number closest to it with maximal error of 0.25

Comment: removing the int will result in it stopping at 3.0 and not 2.5. So in regards to his expected outcome this is right